# Issue on first find match

Tags: regex, node.js

I have worked on regex.  I got issue on the following regex

```
 <tc color="(.*?)">(\s+)?</tc>
```

I need to find exact matched match from the following

```
 <tc color="#47B850"><b>1-1</b></tc></label><para><tc color="#47B850"> </tc>
```

But the above regex matches the entire string but i need

```
 <tc color="#47B850"> </tc>     Note: #47B850 is dynamic text.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the .*, which matches everything upto the last ending tag. If you replace this with e.g. "\S*", or even better, "#[0-9A-Z]+", then it matches only the last occurrence of tc. I tried

```
<tc color="#[0-9A-Z]+">(\s+)?</tc>
```

which matches as you wanted